# Get (index,column) pair where the value is True

Tags: pandas

Say I have a dataframe `df`

```py
  a        b     c
0 False  True   True
1 False  False  False
2 True   True   False
3 False   False  False
```

I would like all (index,column) pairs e.g `(0,"b"),(0,"c),(2,"a"),(2,"b")` where the `True` value is.

Is there a way to do that, without looping over either the index or columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming booleans in the input, you can use:

```
df.where(df).stack().index.to_list()
```

output:

```
[(0, 'b'), (0, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `np.where`:

```
r, c = np.where(df)
[*zip(df.index[r], df.columns[c])]
```

---

```
[(0, 'b'), (0, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.stack().to_frame('col1').query('col1').index.tolist()
```