# How to obtain a list of [index, column, value] lists where the value is not 0 or not missing?

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming that the starting point is a dataframe like ***df***, I am trying to achieve the dataframe ***from_to_value*** in a pythonic way, meaning without iterating through the dataframe:

```py
>>> df
    A   B  C
r1  5 NaN  0
r2  0   6  0
r3  1   4  0

>>> from_to_value
[['r1', 'A', 5],
 ['r2', 'B', 6],
 ['r3', 'A', 1],
 ['r3', 'B', 4]]
```

I have been looking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72215476/get-index-column-pair-where-the-value-is-true) too, but I am not really able to understand how it works to utilise it.

Comment: Why is there no `['r2', 'A', 0]` in the output?

Comment: Because I just do not need it - I can just replace 0s with NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) + `df.stack`; `Series.reset_index()` is then used to return to a Dataframe shape:

```
df.where(df.ne(0) & df.notna()).stack().reset_index().values
```

---

```
array([['r1', 'A', 5.0],
       ['r2', 'B', 6.0],
       ['r3', 'A', 1.0],
       ['r3', 'B', 4.0]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the linked answer, you can use `df.astype('bool')` in `df.where`:

```
df.where(df.astype('bool')).stack().reset_index().values
```

Output:

```
array([['r1', 'A', 5.0],
       ['r2', 'B', 6.0],
       ['r3', 'A', 1.0],
       ['r3', 'B', 4.0]], dtype=object)
```